# Kill [die] dead!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The padding at the end is to get the title up to 15 characters.

To quote the tag wiki: die is a function in several languages. In Perl, die raises an exception or aborts the program. In PHP, die exits the program. In jQuery, the die method removes an event handler.

The [die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/die) tag seems inherently very broad and not particularly useful on its own.

In favor of keeping [die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/die): [Highest Voted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/die?sort=votes).

Contrast with current usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/die

Turtles are dying!

Comment: Just because it has some good questions doesn't make it a great tag... Also, poor turtles.

Comment: Seems rather unfair to such a humble tag.  Picking on the little ones, pffft, anybody can do *that*.  Show us you are a Real Man and kill-off [exception].  When you're done you can continue with [debugging].

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to all "burninate" questions seems to be over here on meta: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

In sum: don't fill up the edit queues. Only try to remove a tag if you have 2000 rep and can DIY.

If you want to remove a tag, just start. Maybe ask for other people's input? Edit all the questions with that tag. Retag them. Improve them. Cast close votes. The tag needs to be emptied.

THEN post a request to burninate.

If you have less than 2000k rep, go answer a question instead.

Comment: I'll go answer questions now.

Comment: Try your luck in the [Tag Burnination](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20577/tag-burnination) chat room for help when there are people. :P

Comment: 2000K rep??????